# ListView.separated returns Null check used on a null value Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to create a list of tiles.
I've used `ListView.separated`. but it keeps giving out errors.

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
> RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#aa680 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>
> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
> Null check operator used on a null value

Here is the code

```
class _NewtilesState extends State<Newtiles> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Container(
      child: Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Person $index'),
                    subtitle: Text("Your Message"),
                    trailing: Text("11:10 PM"),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Divider();
                },
                itemCount: 30)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you put a `Scrollable` without a `shrinkWrap` (the `ListView.separated` into another `Scrollable` - `ListView`. In your particular example you should skip the outer `ListView` and put the `ListView.separated` straight into the `Container`.

[`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) serves a purpose when you put it as a direct child of a flexible widget (so either `Column` or `Row`), making it take up all of the remaining space.

Your `Container` is also redundant, as you don't pass any parameters to it other than `child`.

If you want to have few variable-height widgets in a column like this, you may want to use a [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with [`SliverList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
  return Container(
  child: ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('Person $index'),
          subtitle: const Text("Your Message"),
          trailing: const Text("11:10 PM"),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Divider();
      },
      itemCount: 30),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Container(
  child: Expanded(
    child: ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,  // <--- add this line
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Person $index'),
            subtitle: Text("Your Message"),
            trailing: Text("11:10 PM"),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Divider();
        },
        itemCount: 30),
  ),
);
```